# How to clean up "TreeNode"s with same Text property in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, linq, list, treeview

I have a TreeView which will be populated with some Nodes. The problem is, this nodes can have different `Tag` and `Name` property but some of them can have the same `Text` property.

I want to have only one node from each of above nodes, so the TreeView will have unique nodes by `Text`.

I am trying to make a list of all nodes then filter them, then add the new List to the TreeView. Here is my approach, and I commented the line which does not compile.

```
        //Remove Duplicated Nodes
        List<TreeNode> oldPinGrpNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        List<TreeNode> newPinGrpNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        TreeNode tempNode;


        foreach (TreeNode node in tvPinGroups.Nodes)
        {
            oldPinGrpNodes.Add(node);
        }

        foreach (TreeNode node in oldPinGrpNodes)
        {
            if (newPinGrpNodes.Contains(node.Text)) continue; //this does not compile!
            //How to do a check in the IF statement above?

            //Continue with adding the unique pins to the newList
        }
```

Or if you have any better idea please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried the following Linq query, instead of your check?

```
if (newPinGrpNodes.Any(n => n.Text == node.Text)) continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I'm using `ToLookup` extension method in `System.Linq`:

```
//Remove Duplicated Nodes
      List<TreeNode> oldPinGrpNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
      Dictionary<string, TreeNode> newPinGrpNodes = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();
      TreeNode tempNode;


      foreach (TreeNode node in tvPinGroups.Nodes)
      {
        oldPinGrpNodes.Add(node);
      }

      foreach (TreeNode node in oldPinGrpNodes)
      {
        if (newPinGrpNodes.ContainsKey(node.Text)) continue; //this does not compile!
        //How to do a check in the IF statement above?

        //Continue with adding the unique pins to the newList

        // do something like
        newPinGrpNodes.Add(node.Text, node);
      }
```

As for your compilation error, `newPinGrpNodes` - collection of type `TreeNode` and you try to search `string` there.

**UPDATE:**
For performance, it's better to use Dictionary for searching items: `Dictionary<string, TreeNode>` instead of `List<TreeNode>`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the error. But the code did not work (it just generated same treenodes as old list)

Comment: @Sean87, Ahh, you, probably change `newPinGrpNodes` below in `foreach`

Comment: yeah I think it should be the `oldPinGrpNoeds` :P

Comment: @Sean, I just wanted to say, that List.Any method has linear complexity that is too slow for a big tree. But ToLookup method generate structure that optimized for searching (I hope this is something like hashtable). See edited answer, I've used Dictionary that optimized for searching.

Answer (score 1):

`if(newPinGrpNodes.Any(n => n.Text==node.Text)) continue;`

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach (TreeNode node in oldPinGrpNodes)      
 {        
 if ( from m in  newPinGrpNodesLookup  where m.text=node.Text select m).first ==null)
  continue; 
 }
```